# Load all data of each item in list view or only needed information?

Tags: android, list, load

In my android app, I have a list view and a detail view for selected item. I retrieve the items from my backend server using retrofit.

But is it better to retrieve first the needed information in list view and then to retrieve all the data of selected item in detail view. Or is it better to load all the data of each item directly in the list so that the user does not wait when he selects an item ?

Comment: It's better to detect all the information in the first time and save them in a POJO. One request is better than two requests.

Comment: I would suggest load all at once.. little more wait is appreciated as compared to making another request when user select the data and then load it, and check if loaded before displaying..

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I ask this question because I wonder if the size of the server response can not influence the request time.

Comment: The condition that matters here is the internet speed.

Comment: Ok thank you, I will follow your advice.

Comment: I will post a explanation answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a UX view, it's not satisfying to force your users to wait throughout your application process, it's better to wait on time for all.

From a performance view, each request call has its overhead (i.e. network load),so going for a large request is faster than many small requests.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on the type of item you use

To take the extremes :

if you have a list of songs, you don't want to load the entire song data while loading the list. You just want the title, author, eventually the length and when you click on it to show details, you will load the song at that time or it will that a long time to load the list and you will not have enough memory.

On the other hand, if you have simple items (for example books) where you show the title in the list and the only informations you need is the author and editor, you can load everything in one request.

Things to consider :

- Your internet speed
- the size of the item compared to the size of the data displayed in the list
- the size of the list

Comment: Yes I understand. The decision is not easy to take because even if the items are simple now it will not necesseraly be the case in the future. The database structure and even the webservices are impacted. But to start it seems to me that the best and the easiest way is to load all data.

Comment: if your list is too large or item too complex, you will fill up your memory and risk performance issue, so for complex items you might want request for each item. You can make an alternative that disturb the UX less and that get good performances by loading only the necessary data for the list, and fill your detail view with what you got and the rest will come asynchronously while a progress bar is showing so it does not freeze your UI